# Traduction pour l'anglais "mapping" ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, terminologie, informatique

Le mot anglais **mapping** est fréquemment utilisé en français dans le cadre du développement informatique.

Durant ma scolarité, en cours d'informatique (microprocesseur), j'avais déjà vu traduit **memory mapping** par **cartographie mémoire**, ce qui me semblait un peu étrange au début, mais paraissait finalement acceptable car on y représentait la mémoire à l'aide d'un schéma ou diagramme divisé en plusieurs parties (un peu comme un frise chronologique). On dressait, en quelque sorte une carte de la mémoire.

Cependant, j'entends aussi le terme **mapping** (et le verbe **mapper**) utilisé fréquemment sans lien apparent avec la cartographie dans le sens suivant (c'est un peu technique) :

le fait de  faire correspondre deux structures de données, en associant deux à deux les propriétés/champs qu'elles contiennent.
Par exemple lorsque l'on recopie des données d'une structure A vers une structure B de format différent (les nom ou les type de données peut être différents).

On dit alors que l'on fait un **mapping** de A vers B ou encore que l'on **mappe** les champs/propriétés de A vers ceux de B.

1. Ce sens non-cartographique existe-t-il déjà en anglais ?
2. Existe-t-il un mot français pour dire cela? les termes suivants s'en rapproche mais me semblent pas satisfaisants (imprécis ou lourds) :

> - "faire correspondre A à B"
> - "associer les champs de A à ceux B"
> - "convertir A en B"
> - "calquer B sur A"

Faute de mieux, la francisation **mappage** est peut-être un moindre mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le sens technique « to find or show the connections between two things or groups of things » apparaît bien au dictionnaire pour *[map](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/map) onto*. Je ne connais pas le sujet mais j'ai d'abord été inspiré par le *mappage* en [infographie](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26541035) où on parle de *superposer* et il s'agit donc d'emplois moins techniques dans certains cas. On trouve *mise en correspondance/établissement de correspondances/transposition* ([Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=mapping&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)) qui pourraient aussi être utiles. Hormis *transposer*, voire *réaménager selon un modèle différent*, on peut certainement dire dans certains cas *relier/faire le lien entre*. *Faire l'adéquation/trouver l'identité entre* telle chose et telle autre, *assimiler à* ?

Comment: Ce mappage en infographie, m'évoque finalement le fait d'**appliquer** quelque chose sur autre chose (superposer), ou d'**appliquer une transformation** à chaque élément (pixel) d'un ensemble ce qui rejoint l'**application** mathématique évoquée par @LPH.

Comment: Il s'agit d'un terme mathématiques assez utilisé : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(mathematics)

Answer (score 1):

Oui, ce sens existe en anglais et c'est en fait le sens initial qui a été donné en anglais en mathématiques ; de plus, il n'y a aucun mystère quant à sa signification, c'est tout simplement un synonyme exact du terme « function », dont l'équivalent exact en mathématiques françaises est « [application](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_(math%C3%A9matiques)) » ; ce terme est concurrencé par le terme « fonction ». Un mapping est donc une correspondance *univoque* d'un ensemble vers un autre, cette correspondance étant quelconque, mis à part qu'à n'importe quelle élément dans l'ensemble de départ ne peut pas correspondre plus de 1 élément dans l'ensemble d'arrivée (signification de « univoque »).

En fait le mot « mappage » existe en français ([Wiktionnaire](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/dictionnaire/definition/mappage)), et il est défini en informatique comme suit.

> mappage \ma.paʒ\ masculin
>
> (Informatique) Association des données appartenant à un ensemble (modèle logique de données, base de données de production, champ source) avec les données appartenant à un autre ensemble (modèle physique de données, entrepôt de données, champ cible), de manière que les données du premier ensemble puissent se substituer à celles du second ensemble, ou encore que l’on puisse passer harmonieusement des premières aux secondes.
> La zone du mappage réseau située en haut à droite représente graphiquement la connexion actuelle du réseau. Elle utilise le protocole LLTD (Link Layer Topology Discovery) pour déterminer et afficher la topologie réseau.
> (Philippe Freddi, Windows Server 2008 : Les Services réseaux TCP/IP, Éditions ENI, Saint Herblain (FR), 2009)

[Étymologie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mapping#%C3%89tymologie)  De l'anglais mapping.

[mapping](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mapping#en)

> 3. (Informatique) Mapping.
>    Though dictionaries are the only core mapping type, all of these others are instances of mappings, and support most of the same operations. — (Mark Lutz, Learning Python (5ème édition), O'Reilly, 2013, page 281)
> 4. (Mathématiques) Correspondance, projection, fonction qui attache chaque élément d’un jeu donné à un élément unique d’un autre jeu.

La question suivante sur le SE montre que le concept informatique découle directement du concept mathématique et qu'un mappage est donc une fonction: [SOFTWARE ENGINEERING What does mapping mean in programming?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/307639)

**faire correspondre A à B**: trop général  (mais bon pour la conversation à propos du sujet)

**associer les champs de A à ceux B**: trop général (mais bon pour la conversation à propos du sujet)

**convertir A en B**: pas de la terminologie fonctionnelle

**calquer B sur A**: pas de la terminologie fonctionnelle

La meilleure expression pour l'instant, pour rester dans l'esprit du néologisme initial (mappage), est le verbe « mapper » (que l'on peut trouver parfois en mathématiques) et qui signifie « établir une correspondance ». (mapper A dans/vers B, anglais: map A into B). Il est possible de dire « établir une correspondance de A vers B » mais ce n'est toujours pas très précis parce « correspondance » signifie « relation », ce qui implique qu'à un élément de A peuvent correspondre possiblement deux éléments de B et plus ([correspondance](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_multivalu%C3%A9e)); il faudrait dire « établir une correspondance univoque de A vers B ». « Mapper » ne présente pas cet inconvénient. Donc, la définition ci-dessous est assez informelle.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mapper) mapper \ma.pe\ transitif 1er groupe (voir la conjugaison))
>
> Faire correspondre, établir une correspondance avec.
> ♦ Ce certificat devra être mappé sur son compte d'utilisateur, ce qui lui permettra de pouvoir recouvrir des fichiers cryptés à partir de n'importe où. — (Philippe Mathon, TCP/IP sous Windows 2000, 2001)

---

*supplément apportant une consolidation et l'examination de concepts directement pertinents*

Les explications suivantes étaient initialement destinées à  **user Lambie**, laquelle dans ses commentaires ([1](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45508/traduction-pour-langlais-mapping/45511?noredirect=1#comment92738_45511), [2](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45508/traduction-pour-langlais-mapping/45511?noredirect=1#comment92770_45511)) fait connaitre sa forte impression que le terme « match » est significatif dans cette question de la détermination d'un terme qui correspondrait à la nature du processus impliqué.

- 1 Il faut bien tenir compte du fait que faire correspondre, etc. c'est aussi: matching.
- 2 Je comprends ce que tu dis. Je voulais simplement le signaler. to match one thing with another is faire ou trouver la correspondance entre deux trucs Bien sûr que cela se traduit.....A direct match=une correspondance exacte.

Ces explications ont pour but de dissiper l'idée que ce terme et autres termes de même racine seraient directement pertinents, bien que soit allié naturellement à ce but celui de démontrer  que ces termes concernent bien  ce processus, *mais seulement  accessoirement*. Comme j'ai finalement pensé que ces détails supplémentaires pourraient avoir un certain intérêt, même pour le questionneur, j'ai décidé de les joindre à ma réponse. Cependant, ils ne constituent en gros qu'une mise au point pour l'inaverti sur les différences et similarités, mathématiques,  qui existent entre les termes « relation » et « fonction » ; comme on n'y trouvera rien de plus, doit pouvoir se passer de cette lecture  le lecteur familier avec ces deux termes   et prêt à accepter le   fait que « match » peut être conçu comme signifiant assez exactement « relation (mathématique) ».

« Match » exprime l'idée suivante:  donné  x dans A et y dans B ils ont  les caractéristiques souhaitées (suivant certaines règles) pour aller ensemble, pour satisfaire à un critère préétabli de compatibilité, etc. ; pour revenir à ce que je disais dans un commentaire¹ sans donner de base, ce qui se résume au fait qu'assez souvent, le langage courant ne représente pas la réalité mathématique et donc que l'on ne peut pas s'en servir dans les contextes où on ne peut pas tolérer  d'ambigüité, prenons un exemple de « matching » très « palpable » dans l'existence concrète de tous les jours.
A et B sont deux  ensembles de célibataires, mâles et femelles, respectivement, et des conseillers sont chargés d'établir les paires (x,y) où x est dans A (homme) et y (femme) dans B, ces paires ordonnées (couples) devant satisfaire un ensemble de critères  de compatibilité ; dans A on a x1, x2,… x5 et dans B on a y1, y2, y3,…,y8 (5 hommes et 8 femmes).

Il est tout à fait possible qu'aucun des éléments dans A n'« aille » avec un élément de B, et alors on conclut qu'ils n'y a pas de « matches » pour ces ensembles de personnes, et collectivement,  qu'il n'existe  pas un « matching of elements » entre A et B.

Il est possible qu'au contraire, les spécialistes déterminent qu'il existe au moins une paire (x,y) qui satisfait le critères. Dans ce cas il sera naturel de dire selon la [définition  « naturelle » (OALD 2)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/match_2) de « match » que (x,y) est un « match » et aussi que x est un « match » pour y, et vice-versa. Tout cela semble parfaitement conforme aux notions habituelles, mais un problème se présente déjà : si on n'a pas une paire seulement mais plusieurs qui sont des « matches », comment réfère-t-on à l'ensemble de ces paires ({(a,b), (u,v),…}) ?

Il se trouve que, comble de la dénégation pour une science qui se veut exemplaire en matière de précision, dans les mathématiques modernes, en analogie exacte avec le terme « match » on appelle « (x,y) » une relation, et on appelle aussi « {(a,b), (u,v),…} » une relation, et plus spécifiquement dans un cas précis comme celui-ci, on parle d'une relation entre A et B, mais tout cela est une autre histoire.

Dans la langue anglaise normale  on ne parle pas de « matching » pour l'ensemble, mais ce  n'est pas une perspective irréaliste ; on pourrait peut-être dire « « matching » entre A et B » et alors on aurait un terme qui tout en ayant une possible utilité  dans le langage courant conviendrait parfaitement pour nommer une entité mathématique ; ce serait un synonyme de « relation » tel que ce dernier terme s'applique aux ensembles.

Donc, l'idée de user Lambie est apparemment parfaite, mais en réalité elle n'est que très près du but, ce qui dans les sciences exactes, n'est pas suffisant.  On voit maintenant pourquoi, en revenant à l'exemple.

On a considéré la possibilité d'un ensemble général, {(a,b), (u,v),…}, où a, b, u, v, etc sont des variables, alors que x1, x2,…x5, y1,…y2 sont les noms réels, ou alias si on préfère.

Selon les principes de constitution de ces ensembles (par l'intermédiaire de conseillers), donné un A et un B particulier que l'on choisit encore comme étant A et B du début pour simplifier, on ne trouvera pas impossible de constater que par exemple pour x3 l'élément y4 est un « match » et qu'il se trouve, de plus que l'élément y6 et y7 sont aussi des « matches » pour x3 ;
on pourrait considérer d'autres possibilités avec un plus ou moins grand nombre de ces « matches ». *On est bien d'accord qu'il s'agit encore une fois d'un exemple de ce que l'on peut nommer pour le moment un « matching »*, et si l'on se soucie de la nature mathématique de cette entité on trouve dans la théorie mathématique des relations que l'on appelle cela aussi une relation.

Cependant, si vous consultez les références que je fournis dans ma réponse, vous constaterez (particulièrement dans  celle-ci : [SOFTWARE ENGINEERING What does mapping mean in programming?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/307639)) qu'il n'est pas question de relation mais de fonction. Vous constaterez aussi que lorsque la « correspondance » est mentionnée, il n'est question que d' 1 autre élément et non de « 1 ou plusieurs éléments ».

Selon une définition alternative du concept de fonction mathématique, une fonction est une relation (« matching », if you like) telle que donné n'importe quelle paire de paires ordonnées qu'elle comprend qui sont de la forme (i,j) et (i,k) il s'ensuit nécessairement que j=k.

Dans le dernier exemple on a les « matches » (x3,y4), (x3,y6) et (x3,y7) ; donc, puisque y4≠y6, y4≠y7, etc. (mais y4≠y6 suffit), le dernier exemple est une relation ou « matching », mais ce n'est pas une fonction.

Mentionnons que dans les mathématiques de *Bourbaki*, plus précisément dans leur théorie des ensembles, les relations ont pour nom de définition « correspondance », ce qui montre  le côté inapproprié du terme « correspondance » de plus que encore une fois, celui du terme « match ».

Il s'ensuit que l'utilisation du terme « match » ou même « matching », dans le présent contexte informatique a des connotations insuffisamment précises, mêmes propres à freiner la compréhension et la communication, parce qu'il n'est pas directement pertinent. Cela n'est cependant pas un défaut des  termes « map » et « mapping » ou (alternative française) « mappage », lesquels (deux premiers, le troisième est informatique et a des connotations non mathématiques supplémentaires qui lui sont propres)  signifient exactement « fonction » et de façon entièrement équivalente « transformation » (encore un synonyme de « fonction »), cela, par définition mathématique.

il s'ensuit secondement que l'on pourra dire des choses comme la fonction *f* fait correspondre *y* à *x*, mais pas que *f* est une correspondance ou une relation ou un « matching » parce que cela implique que l'on présume que *f* peut n'être qu'une simple relation, tout au moins dans certains cas, alors que ce n'est pas vrai, *f* étant toujours une fonction. De plus la question c'est trouver un nom pour *f*, pas ce qu'elle fait.

¹<sub>https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45508/traduction-pour-langlais-mapping/45511?noredirect=1#comment92742_45511 @Lambie La langue courante en mathématiques et dans les sciences exactes est en général ignorée au profit de termes définis précisément dans le sujet particulier ; cela signifie que si « mapping » est bien quelque chose de central dans les mathématiques anglo-saxonnes, « matching » n'y trouve pas la même place. Je viens de trouver dans un référence que c'est bien un terme utilisé en mathématiques mais il est spécialisé à la comparativement petite théorie des graphes, un terme obscur qui n'est d'aucune aide dans la théorie des ensemble. – LPH</sub>

Comment: Il faut bien tenir compte du fait que faire correspondre, etc. c'est aussi: matching.

Comment: @Lambie La langue courante  en mathématiques et dans les sciences exactes est en général ignorée au profit de termes définis précisément dans le sujet particulier ; cela signifie que si « mapping » est bien quelque chose de central dans les mathématiques anglo-saxonnes, « matching » n'y trouve pas la même place. Je viens de trouver dans un référence que c'est bien  un terme utilisé en mathématiques mais il est spécialisé à la  comparativement petite théorie des graphes, un terme obscur qui n'est d'aucune aide dans la théorie des ensemble.

Comment: @Lambie Matching est un autre bon exemple mot qui n'a pas d'équivalent direct en français.

Comment: Je comprends ce que tu dis. Je voulais simplement le signaler. to match one thing with another is faire ou trouver la correspondance entre deux trucs Bien sûr que cela se traduit.....A direct match=une correspondance exacte.

Comment: @Lambie J'ai choisi de placer ma réponse à votre commentaire final dans ma réponse au questionneur, parce que la question que vous soulevez est délicate et qu'elle mérite qu'on lui fasse justice, ce qui demande beaucoup de précisions. Vous risquez donc de vous endormir… Si toutefois vous aviez une envie irrepressible d'arriver au fond du problème, et réussissiez à braver les affres de la torpeur grandissante, n'hésitez pas à me poser toute question précise ; je me ferai un plaisir d'essayer ce qui m'est possible pour faire les connections manquantes.

Comment: OK: The main point about matching is this: An item in List B is matched to an Item in List A. For example, in accounting, entries must match. Enfin, je reconnais que ceci ne fait pas vraiment partie de la question. Et en effet, un site décrit ce mapping comme étant une histoire de matching. ha ha. The general notion of match is faire correspondre, and the general notion of mapping is matching. So, faire correspondre A à B, works for BOTH, I guess. Paraît que la torpeur s'est estompée.

Comment: @Lambie Pas de question ! Tout est parfait.

Comment: This was not about literary translation. REPEAT: not about that. It was about my sentence in French in a comment. I do not need references. Also, excuse me for teaching French, but you can't decide on à versus de without context. I would have thought that you knew that.