Can one use the verb 'mapper'?
https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mapper

Faire correspondre, établir une correspondance avec. Ce certificat
devra être mappé sur son compte d'utilisateur, ce qui lui permettra de
pouvoir recouvrir des fichiers cryptés à partir de n'importe où. —
(Philippe Mathon, TCP/IP sous Windows 2000, 2001)

I cannot find any other source apart from wiktionary. So I am wondering.
Can one use the verb 'mapper' in French (of France)? Is it known? Could it be understood? Is it more common to computer science?

Voir éventuellement cette question : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45508/traduction-pour-langlais-mapping

Dans l'informatique peut-être, mais sinon je ne l'utiliserais pas dans la vie courante, et je pense que ce ne serait pas forcément compris par tout le monde.

@Frank En maths? Est-ce qu'on peut l'utiliser ?

@Dimitris Non. Parmi les plus jeunes qui veulent frimer peut-être, mais en général, non.

@Dimitris "common to computer science", what an understatement: it is standard, everyday CS/IT jargon (computer science/information technologies). Dunno about other French-speaking countries than France.

This is what we call an "Anglicisme" which is basically taking an English word or verb and using it as a French word.
Here, "mapper" is exactly what "to map" means while used in an IT context as mentionned by another answer.
I for once use it a lot as I'm an IT Engineer working in an international context and speaking 70% of the time in English for business. But I'm pretty sure that if I use it with my parents they won't understand what it means.

Il existe déjà une question pertinente : Traduction pour l'anglais "mapping" ?.
Dans l'informatique peut-être, [on peut l'utiliser] mais sinon je ne l'utiliserais pas dans la vie courante, et je pense que ce ne serait pas forcément compris par tout le monde. (commentaire de l'utilisateur @Frank).
Parmi les plus jeunes qui veulent frimer peut-être, mais en général, non [on n'utilise le verb en mathématiques] (idem).
